# Comunicación serial python hexadecimal

Tags: python, serialport

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi como se muestra en la foto debo enviar el comando en hexadecimal para poder controlar una máquina por puerto serial RS232. Entonces debo enviar “02 01 20 DD” así tal y como está con espacios y todo.  El problema es que cuando yo envío datos hexadecimales con

```
ser.write(”\x02\x01\x20\xDD”)
```

la máquina no reconoce que son hexadecimales; por lo tanto no reacciona. Intenté ver si había un problema en la máquina, así que conecté mi laptop a la máquina mediante un cable de usb (laptop) a RS232 (máquina) y abrí un programa, SERIAL MONITOR para poder mandar defrente desde mi laptop a la maquina, el programa me decía que si queria mandar hexadecimales debía denotarlo así “$02$01$20$DD” y bingo funcionó, la máquina hizo lo que le pedí.

Entonces hice otra prueba, esta vez conecté mi raspberry (ttyS0) a mi laptop (usb) mediante el cable serial, y empecé a mandar cualquier cosa por el puerto serial desde mi raspberry hasta la laptop. Y la laptop lo recibía sin problemas. Entonces llegue a la conclusión de que el problema está en cómo mando los datos hexadecimales desde mi raspberry a la máquina. Debe ser porque no solo mando un hexadecimal si no que tbm se debe mandar con esos espacios que tiene.

Comment: ¿Y no puedes conectar de alguna forma el programa ese SERIAL MONITOR a un aparato (por ejemplo la raspberry) donde lo reciba un programa escrito por ti en python que pueda volcar lo que recibe? Así podrías ver en qué formato lo envía ese programa, ya que es el formato que funciona, y usarlo en tu programa python. Por otro lado deberías aclarar si es python2 (sospecho que sí) o python3. Y las comillas que has usado en tu código no son correctas, pero imagino que será cosa del copia&pega.

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a aventurar un poco con la respuesta, necesitaría ver el manual de la máquina para estar seguro, pero en situaciones similares (comunicación serie con una máquina X), lo que se debe enviar es una cadena con números representados en hexadecimal, pero no los valores "reales" en hexadecimal.

Dicho de otra forma, en lugar de enviar:

```
ser.write(”\x02\x01\x20\xDD”)
```

Yo probaría a enviar:

```
ser.write("020120DD")
```

O bien con espacios (esa parte no me quedó clara):

```
ser.write("02 01 20 DD")
```

Si eso no funciona, prueba a enviar un array de bytes en lugar de un str (si estás en python3):

```
ser.write(b"\x02\x01\x20\xDD")
```